# Dynamically load Angular templateUrl based on environment variable

Tags: angular

I'm trying to dynamically load my html file into Angular's Component templateUrl based on a new environment variable I've introduced.

It looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-view',
  templateUrl: environment.newUI? './new-view.component.html' : './view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view.component.scss']
})
```

This works locally, however when I deploy it to Azure the HTML doesn't load.

I've been able to confirm that the environment variable is not the issue. When I spin it up using http-server dist/ locally I get the following error:

GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/view.component.html 404 (Not Found)

Any recommendations or advice is appreciated! :)

Comment: maybe its minified in prod version

Comment: IMO it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using Wasif's solution as the basis - thanks Wasif!

First I created a new component which extends my original component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-view',
  templateUrl: './new-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view.component.scss']
})
export class UserViewNewUIComponent extends UserViewComponent {}
```

Then in the router I was able to toggle based on the environment variable like so:

```
 { path: 'user', component: environment.newUI? UserViewNewUIComponent : UserViewComponent }
```

I did try to use absolute paths in the templateUrl  but this didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do this in your root component from where you are using 'app-user-view'

```
<ng-container *ngIf="environment.newUI; else existingUI">
  <app-new-view></app-new-view>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #existingUI>
  <app-view></app-view>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Hey Wasif, thanks for taking the time to comment! 

Unfortunately I'm not creating this from a root component, but instead navigating to it from admin.routes.ts like so:

export const ADMIN_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'user', component: UserComponent }
]

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're facing seems to be related to how the paths are resolved when using dynamic values in the `templateUrl`. Since the templateUrl is resolved at runtime, you need to make sure the paths are correct based on the runtime context.

When working with Angular and dynamic templateUrl, you need to be careful about how paths are resolved. Here's a solution that should work for your scenario:

**1. Use Absolute Paths:** Instead of using relative paths in your `templateUrl`, use absolute paths starting from the root of your application.

**2. Use Angular's APP_BASE_HREF:** Angular provides a service `APP_BASE_HREF` that represents the base URL for the application. This can help ensure your paths are correctly resolved.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-view',
  templateUrl: environment.newUI ? '/new-view.component.html' : '/view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view.component.scss']
})
export class UserViewComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) private baseHref: string) {}
  
  getTemplateUrl(): string {
    return this.baseHref + (environment.newUI ? '/new-view.component.html' : '/view.component.html');
  }
}
```

In this example, we're using the `APP_BASE_HREF` service to get the base URL of the application. Then, in the `getTemplateUrl()` method, we're constructing the absolute path based on the environment and the base URL.

Make sure that you provide `APP_BASE_HREF` in your application's providers. You can do this in your `AppModule`:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [/* ... */],
  imports: [/* ... */],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
  bootstrap: [/* ... */]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

By using absolute paths and taking advantage of `APP_BASE_HREF`, you can ensure that your templateUrl paths are correctly resolved both locally and when deployed to Azure.

Comment: Hey Ketan, thanks for taking the time to reply! I gave the absolute paths ago but it didn't work for me :( 

I'll give APP_BASE_HREF a look later :)